# Where is Maven's settings.xml located on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, repository, maven-2

Where is Maven's settings.xml located on Mac OS?

Comment: "This is the configuration file for Maven. It can be specified at two levels:
 1. `User Level`. This settings.xml file provides configuration for a single user, and is normally provided in `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`.
 2. `Global Level`. This settings.xml file provides configuration for all Maven users on a machine (assuming they're all using the same Maven installation). It's normally provided in `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml`."

Comment: Hey, don't forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 177):

If you use brew to install maven, then the settings file should be in

`/usr/local/Cellar/maven/<version>/libexec/conf`

Comment: For me it was in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.5/libexec/conf/settings.xml`

Answer (score 92):

It doesn't exist at first. You have to create it in your home folder, `/Users/usename/.m2/` (or `~/.m2`)

For example :

[image]

Comment: In the latest MAC OS X Maven is included so .m2 will be created automatically under the `/Users/username/.m2`

Comment: If anyone's wondering what to put in it, look here: http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: As of Mavericks, Maven is not preinstalled. See [Maven not found in Mac OSX Mavericks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678594/maven-not-found-in-mac-osx-mavericks)

Answer (score 45):

if you install the maven with the brew

you can type the command("mvn -v") in Terminal

see Maven home detail

```
mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-04T03:39:06+08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.0/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Answer (score 11):

I found it under /usr/share/java/maven-3.0.3/conf , 10.8.2

Comment: I created a symlink to it from ~/.m2: `ln -s /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml settings.xml`

Comment: On my machine (10.8.2) the default /usr/share/java/maven-3.0.3/conf/settings.xml has everything commented out, so does nothing. Creating a new file in ~/.m2 is probably easiest.

Comment: `/usr/share/java/maven-3.0.3` is the path for global settings, this is a different thing to user-settings; c.f. https://www.eviltester.com/2013/09/maven-settingsxml-global-and-user.html

Answer (score 4):

->It is located in $MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml...
where $MAVEN_HOME is your environmental variable of Maven that you have downloaded. 
Else you can do like this also..
->Path to Maven can also be found from  /etc/bashrc file in mac.
Get Path to Maven from that file and in that Maven directory you can find conf/ directory inside that directory you can find settings.xml of maven

Answer (score 2):

found it under /Users/username/apache-maven-3.3.9/conf

Answer (score 2):

I brew installed it, and found it under /usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.3/conf

Answer (score 2):

For macOS Monterey 12.0.1 and home-brew 3.4.7, it locates at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/{version}/libexec/`

I got this location from `mvn -version`, which gives me

```
Apache Maven 3.8.5 (3599d3414f046de2324203b78ddcf9b5e4388aa0)
Maven home: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.5/libexec
Java version: 18, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/18/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_SG, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "12.0.1", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"
```

Answer (score 1):

After I have downloaded the binary from apache site I, have placed the extracted folder in `/Library` 
So now the location of the settings.xml file is in:

```
/Library/apache_maven_3.6.3/conf
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the best to use `mvn -X` so it should print you locations of settings being used effectively

```
...
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.6/libexec/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/XXX/.m2/settings.xml
...
```

Answer (score 1):

To find out settings.xml

Use `mvn -version` then find out the `Maven home` path in the output of `mvn -version`
for ex:

```
@AMAWQ5XV34HCJ conf % mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.9.0 (9b58d2bad23a66be161c4664ef21ce219c2c8584)
Maven home: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.0/libexec
Java version: 17.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/backup/jdk-17.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_NO, platform encoding: ISO8859-1
OS name: "mac os x", version: "12.6.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac
```

**settings.xml** will be found at

```
<Mavenhome path>/conf
```

forex: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.0/libexec/conf`

Alternately you can also move to .m2 folder, which is ideally located in the root, of not create one and copy to that -m2

```
mkdir ~/.m2
cp /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.0/libexec/conf/settings.xml ~/.m2
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed mavaen using sdkman because of which the other proposed solution didn't work, as they are applicable if the installation is done via Homebrew or as a standalone binary.

for my solution I did "which mvn" in the terminal which returned:
"/Users/samkaz/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current/bin/mvn"

Then after opening the path in a finder and looking around the above directory I found settings.xml in the below folder. "/Users/samkaz/.sdkman/candidates/maven/3.6.3/conf"

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed maven with brew then it must be at the path

```
/usr/local/Cellar/maven/(mvn_version)/libexec/conf/settings.xml
```