# Cloud 9 and Google App Engine w/ Maven 3

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven-3, cloud9-ide

I have set up a new Cloud 9 project and am trying to run my Google App Engine (Java) project. I set the project up as a custom template. I type the following command into the terminal to build my project.

```
marcmouallem@my-project:~/workspace (master) $ mvn appengine:devserver
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error resolving version for 'com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin': Plugin requires Maven version 3.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 15 22:08:53 UTC 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/907M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Mainly concerned with the part that says ...

```
 Plugin requires Maven version 3.0
```

Looking at the version I get ...

```
marcmouallem@my-project:~/workspace (master) $ mvn --version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-14)
Java version: 1.7.0_65
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.14.13-c9" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
marcmouallem@my-project:~/workspace (master) $
```

**Is there anyway I can get Cloud 9 to use Maven 3?**

Comment: Okay, so getting Google App Engine (Java) with maven to work with Cloud 9 is not so straight forward, although it seems possible. You get a sandbox workspace, powered by Docker Ubuntu containers, so you should be able to do anything you want. I'll post a full tutorial when I have it figured out.

Comment: A tutorial would be awesome.

Answer (score 5):

Cloud9 workspaces are Ubuntu Docker containers so you can install Maven 3 the [standard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630055/how-to-install-maven-3-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-13-10-13-04-12-10-12-04-by-using-apt) (making sure to remove Maven 2 as well).

> Checkout the manual installation if your current ubuntu can not install maven via common 'apt-get install maven'.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install maven
> ```
>
> Make sure to remove maven 2 if your ubuntu is not fresh or if you were using maven 2 before:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove maven2
> ```

---

**Update**: Cloud9 now provides Google Cloud Platform workspaces that come with Maven, gcloud tools, and Google Cloud deployment built-in. This may not be perfect for you but could offer you an environment where Maven is already setup for you.

Source: [Google Cloud Platform on Cloud9](https://docs.c9.io/docs/google)

Comment: I got there, I just ran into other hurdles when deploying the dev sever. I'll update the post when I get around to it.