# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystemSession

Tags: rubygems, maven-3

Can you please suggest solution for below problem

github.com/torquebox/jruby-maven-plugins/issues/50

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: de.saumya.mojo.ruby.gems.DefaultGemManager
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystemSession
```

cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound

Comment: Check out the answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19564500/684582

Comment: @Alécio this answer only tells to downgrade maven not how to fix the issue.. Is there a way to keep maven 3.1 and keep rubygems

Comment: Then you have to make sure your plugins are updated according to the table: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound

Comment: Are you using the correct version of this dependency? Could be a class that exist only in an specify version. Check it and let me know if it works.