# How to install maven to mac using terminal without using brew

Tags: macos, maven, terminal, maven-3

I'd like to know how to install maven(apache-maven-3.1.1) to mac using the terminal application without using brew.

*If possible please explain in steps with commands.*

***without using brew!!***

Answer (score 27):

If you have homebrew installed, it should be as simple as

```
brew install maven
```

If you don't have homebrew installed (and you should have it installed) the installation instructions are [here](http://brew.sh/)

Comment: Isn't there any other way?? rather than using brew?

Comment: I am sure there is, but I don't how to do it using anything else. This page might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826881/maven-install-on-mac-os-x

Comment: I already tried that page but wasn't of any help.Anyway thank you very much. :)

Comment: Ah, sorry I could not help more.

Comment: It's okay.I think i will get few more answers later on... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can download the [apache-maven-3.1.1-bin-tar.gz](http://mirrors.ae-online.de/apache/maven/maven-3/3.1.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz) copy that to /usr/share/java via

```
sudo cp apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz /usr/share/java
```

and unpack it via:

```
cd /usr/share/java
sudo tar -zxf apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz 
sudo rm apache-mave-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz
```

and finally add something similiar:

```
PATH=/usr/share/maven/bin:$PATH
```

in your `.bash_profile`.

That's it. But i would recommend to use a more up-to-date version 3.2.1 instead.