# Permanent Maven Installation

Tags: maven

How can I make the maven installation permanent? After downloading the apache-maven to `/usr/local`, I need to print the series of "export" command lines every single time I want to use it. Even after I got the maven to work, maven doesn't work when I restart the terminal.

Added this to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.1/
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

Command-line:

```
$ export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.1/
$ export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
$ export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/home
$ export PATH=$M2:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
$ mvn –-version

Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T12:37:52-05:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.1
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

After restarting command-line:

```
$ mvn –-version
-bash: mvn: command not found
```

Instead of adding `export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin` to `~/.bash_profile`, I also tried adding the other export command-lines that sets M2, JAVA_HOME and PATH. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

After moving the application directory to /usr/local

Make a soft link in /usr/bin for universal access of mvn

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/apache-maven-X.X.X/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
```

Verify mvn installation

```
mvn --version
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Mac, I recommend that you install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (a package manager for OS X). Given that, you can install Maven using the `brew` command, e.g.

```
$ brew install maven
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `/etc/profile.d/maven.sh` with the following content:

```sh
export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.2.1
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

**Mac OSX**
I found two neat tutorials:

1) [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/install-maven-on-mac-osx/)

2) [journaldev](http://www.journaldev.com/2348/how-to-install-maven-on-mac-os-x-mavericks-10-9)

**Win7** You need to set up environment variables. In Win 7, in Start menu you can type *Edit the system environment variables*, then click *Environment variables*. In System variables, add 2 New variables:
**M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.2.1** (this one is custom)

**M2=%M2_HOME%\bin**

After that, among the list of variables, find the one called Path, click Edit, and in the end, after this **;** add **%M2%;**
If you did everything right, and if you have JAVA_HOME set up, then Maven should be permanent.

Comment: wag0325 has a mac, win7 procedure won't help

Answer (score 0):

Do you try putting it in a .profile file instead of .bash_profile?

See [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)

.profile is handled at login, so you need to logout and login for changes to become active.

Answer (score 0):

In the Mac terminal, type below to open text editor

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
open ~/.bash_profile
```

Then in the editor, type:

```
export MAVEN_HOME=~/apache-maven-3.8.1
export PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
```

Close the editor and the contents will be saved. If you check the maven version, you will get response:

```
nisha$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: /Users/nisha/apache-maven-3.8.1
Java version: 16.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "11.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "Mac"
```

Now, even if you close and open the terminal, you will be able to get the above output when you hit `mvn -version`