# How to set Maven Home

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I'd like to set Maven home properly, because it has caused me soo much problems before. Can somebody help me do it properly?

So I was greeted with this when I first tried to run my test program:

[image]

Then when I click preferences:

[image]

This is what terminal tells me my maven home:

[image]

So can somebody guide me? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Really alls you need to do is set:

```
MVN_HOME = <DIR TO MAVEN>
```

in your `.bash_profile` in your home directory. Here's a good SO to help you if you want to read it:
[Maven Install on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826881/maven-install-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to echo your MAVEN_HOME environment variable, check if it
   matches the path printed by running "mvn -version". If not, set
   MAVEN_HOME to this path.
2. Then restart your eclipse to see if eclipse can recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

download maven zip file from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
extract zip file
click on Remote disk---> Show Enclosing Folders ---> Macointosh HD ---> Users
you'll see a folder whose icon looks like Home
this is your root folder or home folder
move your maven folder inside your home directory

now setting the env variable

open terminal

```
vi .bash_profile
```

i- for insert mode

```
export M2_HOME=/Users/kesharwanivikas/apache-maven-3.6.2 
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

Esc and ':wq'

close terminal and open a new one

type

```
mvn -version
```

you'll see that your maven is all set and ready !! Happy coding ✌