# How to avoid the default Maven installed on my MAC

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am facing a problem with maven.I am using MAC.

I installed the Maven 3.0.4 on my laptop.When i go to the Maven folder where i installed it and enter

> /Users/rajesh/Documents/apache-maven-3.2.3/bin/mvn -version

I could see

> Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4;
>   2014-08-12T02:28:10+05:30)    Maven home:
>   /Users/rajesh/Documents/apache-maven-3.2.3     Java version: 1.7.0_71,
>   vendor: Oracle Corporation Java
>   home:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
>   Default locale: en_US, platform  encoding: UTF-8 OS  name: "mac os x" 
>   version: "10.8.5",  arch: "x86_64" family: "mac"

Now I have modified the setting files in it which i need to get the dependencies from the server and added this in PATH variable using

A). sudo nano /etc/paths
B). Enter your password, when prompted.
C). Go to the bottom of the file, and enter the path you wish to add.
D). Hit control-x to quit.

and when i do echo $PATH. I could see my path set on a new terminal.

Now when i am trying to run the maven command from the terminal it is picking the maven located at /usr/share/maven.

Confirmed by

> Rajeshs-MacBook-Pro:bin rajesh$ which mvn /usr/bin/mvn
>   Rajeshs-MacBook-Pro:bin rajesh$ ls -ltr /usr/bin/mvn lrwxr-xr-x  1
>   root  wheel  24 Oct 29 13:15 /usr/bin/mvn -> /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn
>   Rajeshs-MacBook-Pro:bin rajesh$

Could anyone please tell me how can i set my maven which i have installed as the default one ignoring the default one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you like to use an old Maven version and not the up-to-date one (3.2.3).

Comment: I think i have copied the latest version of maven which is 3.2.3 and the one which came with the system is 3.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven Install on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826881/maven-install-on-mac-os-x)