# How to find out what version of maven I am using

Tags: maven

The following command in my terminal is not working (mac user)

```
mvn --version
```

I want to find out what version of maven I have. I know that I have maven because I use it all the time but I am wondering my this command is not working.

Comment: `is not working`... Any error messages?

Comment: -bash: mvn: command not found

Comment: So maven is not in system path ¬¬. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826881/maven-install-on-mac-os-x

Comment: once "mvn" is found it would be "mvn -v" to find out the version maven runs with.

Answer (score 0):

For mac user follow the below link: 
http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-homebrew-os-x-yosemite-10-10-package-manager-unix-apps/

then after you follow those directions enter

```
brew install maven
```