# Maven throwing could not find class error after setting up home path

Tags: macos, maven, osx-elcapitan

I am on mac and Installed maven using the `brew install maven` command. The maven was installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9` path. Then i edited my `~/.bash_profile` file and put the following entries

```
export M2_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9"
export PATH="$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin"
```

now when i try `mvn -version` maven throws the error that

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

Did i configure it wrong ?

**EDIT: Maven folder**

```
$ tree -L 2 $M2_HOME
/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9
├── INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
├── LICENSE
├── NOTICE
├── README.txt
├── bin
│   ├── mvn
│   ├── mvn.cmd
│   ├── mvnDebug
│   ├── mvnDebug.cmd
│   └── mvnyjp
└── libexec
    ├── bin
    ├── boot
    ├── conf
    └── lib
```

Comment: Well that's really weird. Could you post your Maven home directory structure? There should be a `boot` folder containing a jar.

Comment: Updated the question with maven folder. There is no boot folder.

Comment: That is surely a problem. Never installed Maven on a Mac before. Are you sure you installed the version 3.3.9? Maybe your `brew` command is wrong? (never used that also). See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8826881/1743880

Comment: The installation is simply wrong. Just [download it from Maven site](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and [unpackage it to for example](http://maven.apache.org/install.html) `/usr/share/java/` and put `/usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin` into your path and that's it..

Comment: Shall i report it as a brew bug ?

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen as an option:

Create a file ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist with:

```
{
  "M2_HOME" = "/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec";
  "M2" = "/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/bin";
}
```

and restart / log back in. This would make tools like IntelliJ also pick it up.

However in my case, I found some other setup script had installed an export for M2_HOME in my .profile which broke the maven install.