# Install maven in Mac

Tags: macos, maven

Install maven in mac manually. There are several ways of installing maven, but here we explore the manual download from maven, do the installation and verify the installation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven Install on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826881/maven-install-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

- Got to https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
- Download bin.tar.gz file
- Go to your preferred location in your mac and open the .gz file, you will see the maven folder unzipped
- cmd + option + c : Copies the path of the maven folder, paste in text doc output eg: /Users/xxxxxxxxx/Desktop/software/apache-maven-3.8.3
- open terminal,enter cmd : 'vi /Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/.zshrc' press enter
- press i
- export PATH=/Users/xxxxxxxxx/Desktop/software/apache-maven-3.8.3/bin:$PATH
- press esc
- press :wq, press enter
- check version, cmd: mvn --version